# Localization for recommended debug page

Tags: feature-request, localization

Recently I have found a page called [“Recommended (debug)”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug) (link for ruSO, but you can use it on any Stack Exchange site).

Most of page items aren’t available for translation via Transifex. Is it possible to make this page localizable?

I don’t put a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag here because the page officially called “debug”. Though if anybody from SO Team answer me that any page available on international sites should be available to localization I will add that tag.

Comment: Probably not particularly relevant to Int'l sites; the recommendations might show up in your mobile feed if you use one of the mobile apps, but that's a whole 'nother set of problems on its own.